# App file associations in React Native

Tags: react-native

How do I access the data that is passed into my app when I open it through the "Open with..." menu in IOS or "Complete action with" in Android?

Is there a react-native library for this, or some variable that I can get the path to the file that was opened?

The associations themselves I understand are done in Android Studio and XCode, but I just need to get my app to understand what to do when it's used to open a file.

I haven't been able to find anything on this on. Would really appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: Have you found any solutiuon?